# URL Rewriting in IIS with Express

Tags: express, redirect, iis

I want to rewrite all images to a different folder. I'm using IIS and have configured a rule in the web.config to redirect all requests to a node.js file as follows:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="img">
            <match url="\/(.*).img" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/handlers/img.js" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

All requests are now being sent to the img.js file, where based on a condition, I want to redirect to another image file. But IIS now sends that file to the img.js and it ends up as a loop. Is there any way out of this loop?

Comment: Add `<rule stopProcessing="true">`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules First learn how the rule leads to endless redirection loop and then add conditions to break at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below thing to resolve the issue:

set the condition to do not match the pattern:

```
 <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\/(.*).img.js" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
```

or set `<rule name="img" stopProcessing="true">`

```
<rule name="img" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="\/(.*).img" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\/(.*).img.js" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <serverVariables />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/handlers/img.js" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
```